# Unable to start node on Hadoop cdh5.3.1

Tags: hadoop

When i try starting nodes in hadoop, Im getting below error.

```
[hadoop@96 ~]$ start-dfs.sh 
/usr/bin/env: bash: No such file or directory 
Starting namenodes on [] 
/usr/bin/env: bash: No such file or directory 
/usr/bin/env: bash: No such file or directory 
/usr/bin/env: bash: No such file or directory 
/home/hadoop/hadoop/hadoop-2.5.0-cdh5.3.1/sbin/start-dfs.sh: line 109: tr: command not found [hadoop@96 ~]$
```

Please let me know if you have any idea ?

Adding the start-dfs.sh file for more information, I was getting error at tr command ..

```
#---------------------------------------------------------
# ZK Failover controllers, if auto-HA is enabled
AUTOHA_ENABLED=$($HADOOP_PREFIX/bin/hdfs getconf -confKey dfs.ha.automatic-failover.enabled)
if [ "$(echo "$AUTOHA_ENABLED" | tr A-Z a-z)" = "true" ]; then
  echo "Starting ZK Failover Controllers on NN hosts [$NAMENODES]"
  "$HADOOP_PREFIX/sbin/hadoop-daemons.sh" \
    --config "$HADOOP_CONF_DIR" \
    --hostnames "$NAMENODES" \
    --script "$bin/hdfs" start zkfc
fi

# eof
```

Comment: Could you add the contents of `start-dfs.sh` to your question?

Comment: It seems like your `PATH` environment variable is not set properly and hence cannot find `bash` and `tr` programs. Make sure you could run those commands from command line with out any errors and then try to run `start-dfs.sh`.

Comment: Thanks for reply ... **export PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_HOME/sbin:$HADOOP_HOME/bin** .. this is my .bashrc .... When i do echo $HADOOP_HOME its pointing to correct folder. Do you see anything wrong is this path variable ?